# How do I ignore a unit test during dotCover coverage analysis?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, resharper, code-coverage, dotcover

Consider the following repro example (MS Test unit test code):

```
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            SharedMethod();
        }

        [TestMethod, ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
        public void TestMethod2()
        {
            SharedMethod();
            // This is a performance test which will fail during coverage analysis.
            Assert.Fail();
        }

        private void SharedMethod()
        {
            // Should be green
            if (true) ; // NOOP
        }
    }
}
```

`TestMethod2` is a performance test method, which will succeed during "regular" unit test but fail during code coverage analysis (due to the additional overhead). That's fine. I just want that method to be ignored during code coverage analysis, so that my `SharedMethod` is shown as "green" (because it's successfully covered by `TestMethod1`.

[According to JetBrains](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2013/05/29/coverage-filters-in-dotcover/), coverage filters should do that, and, yes, there is a filter active for `ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute`:

[image: screenshot of coverage filters]

However, running Extensions/ReSharper/Unit Tests/"Cover All Tests From Solution" still considers my excluded test when coloring my code:

[image: screenshot of coverage test result]

What did I do wrong? And how do I (easily) exclude my performance tests from Code Coverage analysis?

Comment: There are two types of filters, runtime and coverage, according to [Set up Coverage Filters](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/dotCover__Setting_up_Coverage_Filters.html#) It seems, that you've applied only first one

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski: Good find, but that's not it: `TestMethod2` is already not shown in the coverage window (probably because a runtime filter exists), so I can't add a coverage filter for it.

Answer (score 3):

*(This is a self-answer based on a workaround I found. Feel free to add your own answer, if you found an actual solution for this issue.)*

Apparently, dotCover's coverage filters only affect the coverage statistics shown in the Unit Test Coverage window (% of code covered), not the "code coloring".

As a workaround, you can *generally* exclude tests of certain categories from ReSharper's test runner. To do that, you first add a category to all tests you want to ignore:

```
[TestMethod, ExcludeFromCodeCoverage, TestCategory("Performance")]
public void TestMethod2()
{
    SharedMethod();
    // This is a performance test which will fail during coverage analysis.
    Assert.Fail();
}
```

and then you add that category in Extensions/ReSharper/Options/Tools/Unit Testing/General/"Skip tests from categories":

[image: screenshot]

Your test will still run when started via the regular Visual Studio test runner (e.g. Test/Run All Tests), but it will be ignored by ReSharper and its tools.

Comment: For xUnit tests, use `[Trait("Category", "Performance")]`